# How to log Future's underlying Callable

Tags: java

Given this code,

```
Collection<?> callables = ...
ExecutorService executorService = ...
List<Future<?>> futures = executorService.invokeAll(callables, TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I'd like to know which of the `callables` were cancelled (did not finish in time). I know I can query each `Future` with `.isCancelled()` but that gives me no information as to which exact `Callable` was cancelled.

One solution would be for `Future` to implement a `toString()` method that delegates to the underlying `toString()` of `Callable`. Unfortunately, this is not done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know I can query each Future with .isCancelled() but that gives me no information as to which exact Callable was cancelled.

The list of `Future`s is in the same order as the list of `Callable`s it was created from. So you can keep track that way.